# Bumps/nodes on rocket skin: What are they?

Tags: falcon-9, structural-design

I've wondered for a while now what the many bumps and nodes on a rocket's skin are. Picture below for example (red lines mark bumps). Can someone clarify?

[image: con]

Comment: My wild guess would be patch antennas for GPS or telemetry to ground, or skin temperature sensors, something that has to be on the outside of the tube to do its job.

Comment: That would be reasonable!